# How to load variable Microsoft Teams bot icon?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

For my multi tenant bot Teams app I am trying to provide a different bot name and bot icon per customer. However, it seems that I can only set manually a name and icon once from my Azure Portal. I wonder how to make this variable.

A workaround would be to accept that I can only have 1 bot name and icon, but package manually each customer bot through App Studio / Manifest editor. However I manage to have a unique name, the bot's original name is still presented. See: http://prntscr.com/njf1x9

I am hoping to have a Microsoft Teams app in the app store that has a variable name and icon. If not possible I hope a custom package would not show the original bot's name and icon.

Comment: Whenever an app is sideloaded the bot's icon and name are picked from the Azure service. When the app is installed to a global app store the icon and name are picked from the manifest. Having different icon and name for different customers is not supported right now.

Comment: "Global app store" meaning the Teams app store? Or can I also create a manifest based on the single app/service I have and install that on this customer only? I don't want to publish to the Teams app store a customer specific app.. thanks!

Comment: Installing the app in [Tenant app catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams)
still picks up the icon from the Bot framework. It is not possible to have different icon and name for different customers

Comment: Where can I give feedback? This is insane.. Microsoft is constantly promoting and pushing me to come up with a scalable solution. Now I've made one and MSFT doesnt even allow me to use variable icon + names..

Comment: Btw.. don't take it personally Gousia, I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others: After more talks with MSFT the eventual answer is to come up with an architecture that creates new instances..

Comment: Dear Sjoerd, did you manage to achieve what you wanted ? (I am having a similar question. I have an on-premises installed software which therefore have different domain name depending on the organisation using it. I would like to have a variable domain endpoint that a Teams admin would set before installing the app.)

Answer (score 1):

The ability to support overriding app settings, including bot name, icon, and messaging endpoint, on a per tenant basis is not currently supported. It is something we are considering, but we do not have a timeframe to share.

Comment: Your answer is with regards to the preferred scenario where I just publish 1 app to the Teams app store right? What are the possibilities for repackaging per customer and deploying per customer? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Bill. Any update on the timeline for this feature? For multi-tenant Teams bot apps, it is very much needed. Thanks.