# Is it possible to load another bot with different branding to a Teams app?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot, let's say, NameOne in the bot framework. The app is already published an I wish to keep it that way. However, additionally, a customer wants the exact same bot but with different icon + Name. Is there a way to repackage this bot?

Note: Just adding it to manifest editor only changes the bot name + icon in the notifications and some other places, but not in the main chat area.

Comment: This is a duplicate question.Please refer to :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949014/how-to-load-variable-microsoft-teams-bot-icon?noredirect=1#comment98569490_55949014

Comment: No this is not a duplicate question @Gousia-MSFT .. In that other question I am aiming for automatic / variable names.. Here I would like to zoom in on possible other solution to re-package a bot solution manually

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to do this, no. Teams uses the App Id to distinguish the bot, so you'd have to:

1. Create a new Web App Bot in Azure with new AppId
2. Edit the AppId and AppPassword in your bot's code
3. Upload your edited bot to your new Web App Bot in Azure
4. Create/edit the new bot's manifest and publish to Teams

Judging by [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949014/how-to-load-variable-microsoft-teams-bot-icon?noredirect=1#comment98569490_55949014), it looks like you want to do this at scale. Like I said, there isn't an easy way to do this currently. However, if you're trying to implement the current setup more programmatically, you can use [ARM templates from the new deployment process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=newrg) to speed things up a little. Unfortunately, [it doesn't appear that you can programmatically set branding for an app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-update).

Comment: This has an insane negative impact on my business :'(.. Sure I should have investigated things better myself.. But Microsoft told me to come up with a scalable solution and I really didn't expect that just a different skin was going to be too hard.. Can we escalate this in some way? This should be something that is fixable..

Comment: @SjoerdKoolen Unfortunately I cannot (note, though, that I'm on the botframework team, not Teams). The best I can recommend is filing a feature request on [the Teams UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public)

Comment: Will add it to uservoice, although I am afraid this is not going to help soon enough. Already escalated through my own Microsoft network (I'm a former colleague)