# Set microsoft teams bot username on a per message basis

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Is there a way to set the name of a Microsoft Teams bot on a per message basis?

Slack bots allow this and I would have expected teams to do the same, but I'm not seeing anything in the bot service api docs about it.

I've tried changing the `from.name` property of the [ActivityObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#activity-object) but it gets ignored (why that property exists I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55951972/10860086):

> The ability to support overriding app settings, including bot name, icon, and messaging endpoint, on a per tenant basis is not currently supported. It is something we are considering, but we do not have a timeframe to share.

The only way to accomplish this would be to design your architecture such that you're literally creating a new Bot Channels Registration with each message. I do not recommend this approach.