# Dynamically change Microsoft Teams bot name and icon

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

We have a bot service running in MS Azure and a corresponding Teams app. This bot service is used by multiple customers. Requirement is to allow customers to change the bot name/icon that is shown in the Teams chat (please refer image below).

We can change the name and icon by changing it in the Teams App. However, this will require creating a separate Teams app for each customer. Is it possible to control this via the bot service code running in Azure? We want to do it programmatically based on logged-in user's domain. Is there anyway to do it?

[image: click here to show image]

Edit: [Found a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949014/how-to-load-variable-microsoft-teams-bot-icon)

Thanks
Vivek

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible within a single bot - it's set at the level of the the bot registration, in Azure, and so can't be changed tenant by tenant in Teams, for example. You'd need to create a bot for every customer (tenant), or go with a generic name and image. You *can* of course customize the welcome message, responses from the bot, etc.